# Symfony2 buildForm - adding entity type input with count

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I try to add a input with count to generate a registration number.
eg(2/2014)
2 -> the count + 1
2014 -> the year

I use this code:

```
            ->add('registration_number', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'FrontBundle:User',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->select('count(u.id)')
                    ->groupBy('u.id')
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getResult();
            },
        ))
```

but I get the error:

> Expected argument of type `Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder`, `array` given.

I tried this solutions with no success

1- removing the line ->`getResult()`.

```
return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->select('count(u.id)')
                    ->groupBy('u.id')
                    ->getQuery();
```

The error :

> Expected argument of type "Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder",
>   "Doctrine\ORM\Query" given

2- removing last 2 lines

```
return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->select('count(u.id)');
```

The error :

> Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: remove the line `->getResult()`.

Comment: I have already try this but i get the error : Expected argument of type "Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder", "Doctrine\ORM\Query" given

Comment: Sorry, try removing last 2 lines and it should work...

Comment: No, it's still not working. I have another error: Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given

Comment: Please update the question with full error stack...

Comment: What is the expected result of your query? A single value, as suggested by the `count()`? Or an array of the number of times each user appears in the User entity, as suggested by `groupBy`?

Comment: I try to generate a registration number by using the count +1 and concatenat with the current year.

Comment: Note that you can notify commenters of your response by preceding your comment with `@` and user name, e.g., @geoB

Answer (score 2):

You're not selecting an entity result from the `EntityRepository`. A wild guess: it returns a `COUNT(u.id)` string instead of a collection of entities.

Looks like `'entity'` form type is not really fit for your task. If you need to add a registration number, I believe it should be a text input (or maybe a hidden field, depends on what you want). So, you should not add an entity field, you should instead generate the registration number beforehand and pass it alongside with the form data. If you're creating a form for a user, that should maybe look like this:

```
// Your controller action
$user = new \FrontBundle\Entity\User();

$qb = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('FrontBundle:User')->createQueryBuilder('u');

$regNumber = $qb->select('count(u.id)')
                 ->groupBy('u.id')
                 ->getQuery()
                 ->getResult();

$user->setRegNumber($regNumber);

$form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);

// Your form
// @var FormBuilderInterface $formBuilder
$formBuilder->add('regNumber', 'text', array());
```

Answer (score 0):

If the registration number is generated when the form is opened there is a possibility of having the same number assigned to more than one user.  This can be minimized by assigning the registration number when the form is submitted.  In the following I also assume that there exists a property `registrationNumber` in the User entity. It goes something like this:

#### Controller

```
...
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManger();
...
if ($form->isValid()) {
    ...
    $allUsers = $em->getRepository("YourBundle:User")->findAll();
    $n = count($allUsers) + 1;
    $date = new \DateTime();
    $year = date_format($date, 'Y');
    // make it sortable
    $l = strlen($n);
    $regNumber = $year . str_repeat('0', 5 - $l) . $n;
    $user->setRegistrationNumber($regNumber);
    ....
```